# SSRS puts # in front of field name and scrambles the report columns

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I use sql server data tools for visual studio 2013 which has SSRS in it. (please don't laugh)

This query, which I am using for my report, works just fine in Sql Server Management Studio:

`select  U.ConsumerNumber as GranteeCust, U.FirstName as GranteeFirst, U.Lastname as GranteeLast,  pc.create_date as Pwd_Chg_Date, sg.create_date as Linking_Chg_Date, sg.first_name as First, sg.last_name as Last, sg.user_type, sg.consumer_number as Account,  sg.login_username as Linking_Chg_Login, sg.description as Linking_Chg_Description, sg.changed_by as Linking_Chg_ChangedBy, sg.ip_address as Linking_Chg_ip,    pc.login_username as Pwd_Chg_Login, pc.description as Pwd_Chg_Description, pc.changed_by as Pwd_Chg_ChangedBy, pc.ip_address as Pwd_Chg_ip, ('{' + replace(LEFT(sg.description,CHARINDEX(',',sg.description)-1),'Grantee ','') + '}') as Grantee from alkami.flux.ProfileChanges sg  --inner join on real report.  this is temporary... left join alkami.flux.profilechanges pc on sg.consumer_number = pc.consumer_number and pc.profile_change = 'User Update Password' and abs(datediff(dd,pc.create_date,sg.create_date)) <= 7  left join alkami.flux.UserData U on ('{' + replace(LEFT(sg.description,CHARINDEX(',',sg.description)-1),'Grantee ','') + '}') = U.user_identifier where sg.profile_change = 'SharedAccessGranted' and abs(datediff(dd,getdate(),sg.create_date)) <= 30`

When I Drag and drop the First field, and it will put # in front of First (for first name).
Same with Last.
[Hash in front of field names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Tld.png)

Preview of report reveals something is way off….looks like the contents are scrambled…wrong field is in the wrong place, and some fields are not populated:

[Scrambled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD9yq.png)

even if I delete my report design and create a simple 2 column report with first name and last name it does this.  it puts fields in my dataset that are not the fields that I picked, and puts a hash in front of the field names in design mode.

Strange thing about Stack overflow is when I get it nicely formatted code, as modified by poorsql.com, it doesn't accept it, and I think it does a better job in spacing, but it is not liked and I cannot hit post button, so sorry about that.... maybe that is good take away for monitors to improve their design....